# $f:S→S$ is bijective. and $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ Then how can i get the number of $f?$

Tags: combinatorics

$f:S→S$ is bijective. and $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ Then how can i get the number of $f$ ?

**approach**: I tried to subtract the amount of $f(f(x))=x$ of the amount of all $f$. But i knew there can be f that has part of $f(f(x))=x$ and other is not.

Comment: There are $7!$ permutations of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Answer (score 1):

If the function $f:S→S$ is a bijective and $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, then the number of functions $f$ from $S$ to $S$ are just different arrangements of numbers $1,2,...,7$. Since these numbers can be arranged in $7!$ different ways ,thus we conclude that there are $7!$ different bijective functions from $S$ to $S$.

In order to view above detail in more depth. Consider a bijective function $f:\{1,2\}→\{1,2\}$. We see there are two $2!=2$ bijective functions from $\{1,2\}$ itself. These two functions are namely $f_1$ and $f_2$ s.t $f_1(1)=1$, $f_1(2)=2$ and $f_2(1)=2,f_2(2)=1$.

Comment: sorry but i need f(f(x)) ≠ x

Comment: @Chokbitt  This is a correct answer to the question that you wrote.  If you intended to write a different question, then you should ask a new question in which your question is clearly stated in both the title and the body, explain what you have tried, and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

We look for the opposite: the number of functions that satisfy $f(f(x))=x$. One can use some neat methods in Algebraic Combinatorics to answer this question. A nice reference is the first chapter of Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 1*.

We begin by associating each bijection from $S\to S$ with a permutation $w$ in $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Each permutation has a cycle representation: for example,
$$w=(2)(6)(14)(375)=4271365$$
represents the permutation that keeps the $2$nd and $6$th object in place, interchanges the $1$st and $4$rth, and "cycles" the $7$th to $3$rd, $3$rd to $5$th, and $5$th to $7$th. We let $c_i$ denote the number of cycles of length $i$, so for the given example $c_1=2$, $c_2=c_3=1$. We now know to look for the number of permutations that only contain cycles of lengths $1$ and $2$.

Let us define the cycle indicator polynomial
$$Z_n(t_1,\dots,t_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_w t_1^{c_1}\dots t_n^{c_n},$$
where we sum over all permutations.

If $e_2(n)$ denotes the number of permutations satisfying $w^2=1$, where $1$ denotes the identity, then
$$e_2(n)=n!Z_n(t_1=t_2=1, t_2=t_3=\dots=t_n=0)$$

Theorem (1.26) in Stanley's book has straightforward proof that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty Z_n x^n=\exp\left(t_1 x_1+t_2 x^2/2 +t_3x^3/3+\dots\right). $$
Thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_2(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\exp\left(x+ x^2/2\right).$$
Here $n=7$. So taking $7$ derivatives of the LHS and then setting $x=0$ gives (using Mathematica)
$$e_2(7)=232,$$
so the number that don't satisfy $f(f(x))=x$ is
$$7!-e_2(7)=4808.$$

Answer (score -1):

In below context, ${S}=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n-1,n\}$

#### Number of $f: {S}\rightarrow {S}$ which is bijective

i.e., count how many $n$-permutaions.

$$
n!
$$

#### Number of $f: {S}\rightarrow {S}\text{ such that } \forall x \in S, f(f(x)) \neq x$ and $f$ is bijective

i.e., count how many permutations whose cycle decomposition has no 2-cycles.

$$
n-\operatorname{UnsignedStirlingNumberOf1stKind}(n,2)
$$

#### Reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind